# how to set a value to composite primary key in hibernate application

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a Java bean/model class with JPA annotation as below. This class has a composite key as shown below. In `DAO.java` how do I set the key to this composite key?

```
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "ratioFunctionId", column = @Column(name = "ratio_function_id", nullable = false, scale = 0)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "expressionId", column = @Column(name = "expression_id", nullable = false, scale = 0))
})
public RatioFunctionExpressionId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(RatioFunctionExpressionId id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set a value for this attribute, just create a new instance and assign it:

```
RatioFunctionExpressionId newId = new RatioFunctionExpressionId();
newId.setRatioFunctionId(aFunctionId);
newId.setExpressionId(anExpressionId);
aRatioFunctionExpression.setId(newId);
```

Remember that being `RatioFunctionExpressionId` an `@Embeddable`, it doesn't need an id of its own, because it doesn't represent an Entity on its own. It's only meant to provide grouping of property definitions for easy composition and modularity.

Comment: @nagch Great, I had a second read at the question and figured out you were asking something else. I've updated the answer.

Comment: to be more clear. i want to create DAO for this. I have written save() . now to test the daoimpl.java, i have to write a junit method to test it. here i want to know how to set the composite key to this java bean?

Comment: Just instantiate a `RatioFunctionExpressionId` and call `RatioFunctionExpression#setId()`. Did you see the updated answer?

Comment: Hi Xavi, could you please help me with the below error: when i run the test case:

Comment: path expression ends in a composite value: ratiofunct0_.id [from RatioFunctionExpression ratioFunctionExpression where ratioFunctionExpression.id = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: path expression ends in a composite value: ratiofunct0_.id [from com.moodys.mis.cfg.ratios.models.RatioFunctionExpression ratioFunctionExpression where ratioFunctionExpression.id = ?]

Comment: code:RatioFunctionExpression ratioFunctionExpression = null; 
  RatioFunctionExpressionId ratioFunctionExpressionId=null;
  try {
   ratioFunctionExpressionId = new RatioFunctionExpressionId();
   ratioFunctionExpressionId.setRatioFunctionId(ratioFunctionId);
   ratioFunctionExpressionId.setExpressionId(expressionId);
   List<RatioFunctionExpression> instance = (List<RatioFunctionExpression>) template.find("from RatioFunctionExpression ratioFunctionExpression where ratioFunctionExpression.id = ?", ratioFunctionExpressionId);
   logger.debug("get successful");